# Print figure when plot finishes, works on debug mode but not in runtime

Tags: matlab

I've used GUIDE to develop a Matlab App that allows loading images and performing analysis on them. In short, I show the image by using *imshow* and add markers and text (by using *plot* and *text* functions respectively). I want to print the figure to a file, including the markers and the text, but strangely it is only printing the original image. On the other hand, when I put a breakpoint before the print command, it works perfectly, so it seems to me that it is a problem of "timing". However, I have tried "drawnow" and "pause(X)" to no avail, so I was wondering whether I'm doing something wrong or there is another way to do this. 
This is the pseudo-code which is inside an "updateImage()" function (called by a button):

```
cla(handles.h_image); %clear image axes. "handles" is a structure created by GUIDE containing handles to all objects in the figure. "handles.h_image" is the handle to the axes of my image
im = imshow(ch_data,'Parent',handles.h_image); drawnow %ch_data contains the image
hold on
for n = 1:length(myarray) % myarray is not actually too big, length of about 100 
    x1 = whatever; x2 = whatever; y1 = whatever; y2 = whatever;
    plot([x1 x2],[y1 y2],'linestyle','-','linewidth',1,'color',[211 99 252]/255);
    text(x1, y1, num2str(n),'Fontsize',10,'color',[208 240 255]/255);    
end
pause(5) %tried different values, but still not working in runtime
cd(results_dir) 
print(handles.container,'-dtiff', '-opengl', '-r300', 'myimagename');
```

EDIT: I've tried that part of the code on a separate script and it works fine...

```
f = figure;
im = imshow('peppers.png'); drawnow 
hold on
r = randi([1 size(im.CData,1)],1,200);
for n = 1:50 
    x1 = r(n); x2 = r(n*2); y1 = r(n*3); y2 = r(n*4);
    plot([x1 x2],[y1 y2],'linestyle','-','linewidth',1,'color',[211 99 252]/255);
    text(x1, y1, num2str(n),'Fontsize',10,'color',[208 240 255]/255);    
end
print(f,'-dtiff', '-opengl', '-r300', 'myimagename');
```

Comment: It would be nice to have a minimal, working example that we could try

Comment: Have you tried it without opengl? I've had funky behaviour with that in the past...

Comment: @LuisMendo, problem is that original code comprises hundreds of lines and it is integrated as a GUIDE app. I've posted the code (I think) is relevant. Nevertheless (see my Edit), I've tried that code alone and it works perfect, so there must be some mess with the GUIDE autogenerated code.

Comment: @Justin yes, I tried without opengl and problem remains. In fact I tried the code I posted alone, and it works (even with opengl)

Comment: have you tried `drawnow` immediately before the print statement?

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes, not working either. I guess it is some kind of weird behavior introduced by GUIDE...

Comment: Whenever anyone is using `print` I feel obligated to suggest the far superior `export_fig` from the FEX. Often works way better. I know this is not the desired solution, but it may solve your headaches, I'd  give it a try

Comment: @CarlosBorau I see. Yes, the second code snippet also works fine here (R2017b, Win10)

Answer (score 0):

One difference between your two code snippets is that in the first you are saving 'handles.container' while in the other it's a figure handle.

Try

```
f = ancestor ( handles.h_image, 'figure )
print ( f, ..... )
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but in my code handles.container is actually the figure ancestor of handles.h_image, so problem is still there. I guess I have to accept it is a kind of bug because it works perfectly fine while debugging.

Comment: What is in the file that is saved? Is it an empty image?  Can you see the image on screen?

Comment: It prints whatever I plotted with the "imshow" command, but not the markers printed by the "plot" command and the text printed by the "text" comand. In debug mode everything is printed